# why this line give me error about getDownloadUrl() method how can i solve it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am going to make two apps, client and admin apps; but this time it give me an error in `getDownloadUrl()` anyone can tell me how to solve it

if i use `getUploadSessionUri()` then my image is not loaded in client app

please help me how to solve it

**this code on client app-**

```
Upload1 upload = new Upload1(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(), taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(),editText1.getText().toString());

String uploadId1 = databaseReference.push().getKey();
```

**this code on admin app-**

```
Upload1 upload = new Upload1(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(), taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString(),editText1.getText().toString());

String uploadId1 = databaseReference.push().getKey();
```

Comment: Show your error code??

Comment: `give me an error` which error?

Answer (score 1):

`taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` is deprecated when uploading a file on firebase; you can use below instead

```
reference.putFile(uri)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final Task<Uri> firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                firebaseUri.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        // complete the rest of your code
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: @PavanSharma glad that you solve it.. if you feel like a solution, If it answered your question, please click the checkmark (✓) to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is removed in recent version. You will need to get the download URL from the storage reference.

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png' in uri
    System.out.println(uri.toString());
 }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle any errors
 }
});
```